# conditionally concatenate text from multiple records in vba

Tags: vba, excel, string-concatenation

Sample Data:
    UniqueID Description              ConsolidatedText
    Str1     Here is a sentence       Here is a sentence
    Str2     And another sentence.    And another sentence. And some words
    Str2     And some words
    Str3     123                      123
    Str4     abc                      abc ###"
    Str5     ###

I have a number of records (~4000) each with a UniqueID value (text) and a text field (potentially quite lengthy) which is a user-entered description of the data. I need to consolidate the spreadsheet by concatenating all the descriptions into a single record where there are multiple occurrences of the UniqueID value. Generically, I want to loop through the range of potential values and say "if UniqueID is equal, then take all of the Description values and concatenate them together in a single row (either the first row or a new row) then delete all the old rows." Basically, I want to create the ConsolidatedText field in this sample data, and then also delete the extra rows. This is beyond my VBA programming abilities, and any help with the structure of this macro would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [conditionally concatenate text from multiple records in vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043629/conditionally-concatenate-text-from-multiple-records-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()
    Dim d As Object
    Dim c As Range, sId, sDesc, k

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A4002")
        sId = Trim(c.Value)
        sDesc = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If Not d.Exists(sId) Then
            d(sId) = sDesc
        Else
            d(sId) = d(sId) & "   " & sDesc
        End If
    Next c

    DumpDict ActiveSheet.Parent.Sheets("Summary").Range("A2"), d

End Sub

Sub DumpDict(rng As Range, d As Object)
Dim k
    For Each k In d.Keys
        rng.Value = k
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = d(k)
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Next k
End Sub
```