# Combine rows with identical fields of information

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook (C:\DOORS.xlsm) with the following data:

```
 A           B            C               D
100       Type A     Description1      Remarks1
102       Type A     Description1      Remarks1
103       Type C     Description2      Remarks2
104       Type D     Description3      Remarks3
```

I'm still learning VBA and would like to know what i should research to be able to sort the above data to look like this.

```
    A           B            C               D
 100, 102    Type A     Description1      Remarks1
   103       Type C     Description2      Remarks2
   104       Type D     Description3      Remarks3
```

I think I would use a loop to go thru each cell and verify if it matches another entry, still trying to wrap my head around the concepts of loops,but I was told to avoid them if possible. Then i believe you would use something like a sort function inside the loop? Let me know if i can improve my question or clarify anything. I'm trying to ask good questions and would love some constructive criticism =).

original title: Trying to learn VBA and need help pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Will description and remarks always be identical for any Type?  I.e., the only concatenation would be of the value in column A?  You might want to look at something like this (and its duplicates) to point you in the right direction.  I'm almost certain you'll need a loop.  Loops are not inherently bad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043629/conditionally-concatenate-text-from-multiple-records-in-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Before writing any code, go to the VBE's Tools ► Options and put a checkmark beside **Require Variable Declaration** on the **Editor** tab. This will save you debugging time if you misspell a variable when typing your code. This option will be remembered and the following will be automatically placed into the Declarations area of each new module code sheet you create.

   > Option Explicit
2. Start creating your sub procedure and type out any variables that you already know you are going to need..

   > Sub data_Rollup()
   >       Dim rw as Long, strA as String, strB as String
   >       'lots to go here
   >    End Sub
3. Define your working environment with one or more [With ... End With statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). Use the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) to isolate your row and column references to the 'island' of data originating in the worksheets A1 cell.

   > With Worksheets("Sheet1")
   >       With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
   >           'all of the working code here
   >       End With
   >   End With
4. [Range.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) your data on column A first then columns B, C and D. You can only sort in three key columns at a time so you will want to sort column A first to get those ordered then B, C and D to match the duplicates. You should know whether your data has column header labels or not. Do not rely on Excel to [xlGuess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb216447(v=office.12).aspx).

   > .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
   >                         Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
   >       .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
   >                         Key2:=.Columns(3), Order2:=xlAscending, _
   >                         Key3:=.Columns(4), Order3:=xlAscending, _
   >                         Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
5. Loop from the bottom to the top. You are going to want to get rid of rows that you combine with identical rows and if you progress from the top to the bottom while deleting rows you run the risk of skipping over a row. e.g. you delete a row and everything shifts up; you increment (loop) and move on to the next row but in reality, you've skipped over the one that was just shifted up.

   > For rw = .Rows.Count¹ To 2 Step -1
   >           'more to come here
   >       Next rw
6. Concatenate the strings from columns B, C and D together for the current row and the row above. Use either the [LCase function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264497.aspx) or the [UCase function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264252.aspx) to remove case-sensitivity from the text string comparisons. If a match between the three information columns is found, [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) the row's column A contents with a delimiter then use the [Range.Delete method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223863(v=office.11).aspx) to permanently remove the row.

   > strA = Join(Array(.Cells(rw, 2), .Cells(rw, 3), .Cells(rw, 4)), ChrW(8203))
   >       strB = Join(Array(.Cells(rw - 1, 2), .Cells(rw - 1, 3), .Cells(rw - 1, 4)), ChrW(8203))
   >       If LCase(strA) = LCase(strB) Then
   >           .Cells(rw - 1, 1) = Join(Array(.Cells(rw - 1, 1), .Cells(rw, 1)), ", ")
   >           .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
   >       End If
7. When you think it looks right, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to compile. Deal with undeclared variables or missing clause closes as necessary.
8. When it compiles without error, place the cursor anywhere within the procedure and start tapping <kbd>F8</kbd>. This will step you through the procedure roughly line-by-line so you can see what is happening. Use the **Watch Window** and hover the cursor over variables to see current states and values. If you are confident with a section, place the cursor on a working code line below the section and tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to *Run-to-cursor.
9. When it runs through reliably without error you can look into adding runtime optimizations like [Application.ScreenUpdating property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx) and others.

Nothing to it.

---

¹ <sub>Since you are working within the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx), the [.Rows.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195745.aspx) is the total number of rows in the .CurrentRegion.</sub>

Comment: Thanks so much @Jeeped. I have not had the time to go thru this yet but I'll let you know if I have any questions. Thanks Again, Have A Wonderful Thanksgiving!

Comment: @Jeeped Just because I want to know and because there was no comment in your edit: Why did you use blockquotes for the code instead of codeblocks and why did you revert my edit? Code has to be formatted as codeblocks according to the formatting rules if I read them correctly. And I only see disadvantages if you don't use them. So I guess you have got another reason for this decision that I don't see at the moment?

Comment: I *think* it was because I wanted to keep the 'code blocks' in the number sequence HTML which (if I remember correctly) I struggled with originally.